# Cannot define aliases in metasploit framework docker image

Tags: docker, metasploit

I'm trying to use the [Docker metasploit image](https://hub.docker.com/r/metasploitframework/metasploit-framework) within my own `Dockerfile` config which is this one:

```
FROM metasploitframework/metasploit-framework

WORKDIR /usr/src/my-awesome-tool

COPY . .

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --editable .

RUN echo 'alias msfconsole="/usr/src/metasploit-framework/msfconsole"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'alias msfvenom=/usr/src/metasploit-framework/msfvenom"' >> ~/.bashrc

# The metasploit-framework docker image needs to stay here.
WORKDIR /usr/src/metasploit-framework

ENTRYPOINT ["my-awesome-tool"]
```

The image is created perfectly with `sudo docker build -t my-awesome-tool .` and I run it as `sudo docker run -it --rm --privileged --network=host my-awesome-tool` but, if I check if the alias `msfconsole` was created, it was not.

Answer (score 1):

First you should add your user to the docker group instead of using sudo all the time.

Apparently the image does change the entrypoint. The `.bashrc` file gets written to `root` which we can't access at runtime and we are a different user when running compared to while building. I tried writing the alaises to `/etc/profile` but that is not picked up. Without changing the entrypoint of the image the simplest solution is probably something similar to this:

```
RUN echo "alias msfconsole='/usr/src/metasploit-framework/msfconsole'" >>/usr/src/metasploit-framework/.profile
RUN echo "alias msfvenom='/usr/src/metasploit-framework/msfvenom'" >>/usr/src/metasploit-framework/.profile
```

and running `. .profile` on startup.

Comment: But it did not work, the `.bashrc` file is not created.

Comment: I also missed that the image is alpine based. if you don't want to source it every start you would need to write it to an ``*.sh`` file in ``/etc/profile.d/``

Comment: I just run the two lines you edited, but it did not work as well, I don't know what you mean with running `. .profile`

Comment: You need to "source" the alias every container start. Basically running the commands on every start.

Comment: This is the current code https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/AVMod/blob/master/Dockerfile so, the complete code would be like that?

Comment: the envs aren't saved and the image does not source normal shell files... so no, I have not a realy solution that does not require manual command running.